# Node.js: Can't access mysql within createServer?

Tags: mysql, node.js, https

I'm trying to build a server in node.js that'll take a request from a client, access a mysql server on the server, and send data from that server to the client. I am able to access the mysql server outside of the createServer but I can't put the sql query within the createServer method.

Example of what doesn't work:

```
var jellies;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var sql = "SQL STATEMENT";

    sqlConnection.query(sql, function(err, result) {

        if (err) throw err;

        jellies = result;

    }

res.write(JSON.stringify(jellies));

}).listen(port);
```

Example of what does work:

```
var jellies;

var sql = "SQL STATEMENT";

sqlConnection.query(sql, function(err, result) {

    if (err) throw err;

    jellies = result;

}

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

res.write(JSON.stringify(

}).listen(port);
```

console.log(jellies) after the query is made produces null for the first function. Are you just not allowed to do anything in http.createServer()? Any ideas to work around this?

The error I get is: TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer. It calls back the the line for htts.createServer();

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try this?

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var sql = "SQL STATEMENT";

    sqlConnection.query(sql, function(err, result) {

       if (err) throw err;

       res.write(JSON.stringify(result));

    }

}).listen(port);
```

Comment: *"Can you please try this?"* That's useless information. Your answer is more useful for visitors if you explain the mistake the OP has made and what you changed and why you changed it.

Comment: Thank you @FelixKling. 
This is my second answer on stackoverflow. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Figures the problem I worked on all yesterday would get solved by a friend online in a few seconds.

For the next person that might struggle with this all that needs to be fixed is moving res.write() and res.end() into the sql query function.